# Unable to explain the output for the following C++ snippet

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, output, memset

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int dp[5][6];
   memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
   dp[1][0]=0;
   for(int i=1;i<=9;i++){
      dp[1][i]=1;
   }
   cout<<dp[2][0]<<endl;
   cout<<dp[3][0]<<endl;
 }
```

This above snippet produces an unexpected output:

```
1
0
```

However when I change the dp array size to dp[100][100], 
I get the expected output as:

```
0
0
```

I tried printing the 2D matrix size as well:

```
sizeof(dp)/sizeof(int)
```

I am getting the correct values : 30 in case of dp[5][6] and 10000 in case of dp[100][100].
I compiled and executed the code using a standard g++ compiler in linux.
Can someone explain to me the cause of this erroneous output.

Comment: try printing sizeof(dp) , I have a feeling that it's actual value differs from what you expect.

Comment: Your `for` loop edits elements out of bounds of the array. This is undefined behaviour. It most likely start to overwrite `[2][0]` to `[2][3]`, since arrays are continuous in memory, but you can never be sure.

Comment: I think you have UB from `dp[1][6]=1;`. out of bound access.

Comment: sizeof(dp) is giving an expected answer of 120 (4*5*6).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen This is true. I am forcefully doing that. I am unable to explain how is it changing an element which is in range and not out of bound? Does the compiler wraps up indices in 2D matrices?

Answer (score 2):

The dimensions of your array are `[5][6]`. So when you try doing `dp[1][i] = 1` with `i` from `1` to `9`, at some iteration, `dp[1][6] = 1` is done. As number of elements in 'row' is `6`, it's doing same operation as `dp[2][0] = 1`, as all elements of that two-dimension array are stored sequentially.

So basically when you try to access `dp[1][i]`, it's like `startOffset + 1 * rowSize + i`. And `i` is greater then row size.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox No, it's not UB. The elements of array are required to be stored sequentially. Imagine this array would be declared instead like `typedef int row_t[6]; row_t dp[5];`. `int`s inside of each `row_t` object are stored sequentially, and each `row_t` objects are stored sequentially in `dp`-array. `sizeof(row_t)` is `6 * sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(dp)` is `5 * sizeof(row_t)`. There is no way those elements are not stored sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, it is poor practice in C++ to use `memset` to zero-initialize arrays. The best practice is to use [aggregate initializer syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
int dp[5][6] = {}; // Zero-initialize.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not good code style, but since I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve I won't suggest how to improve it but just answer your question: explain the output.

In the first case

```
int main() {
   int dp[5][6];
   memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
   dp[1][0]=0;
   for(int i=1;i<=9;i++){
      dp[1][i]=1;
   }
   cout<<dp[2][0]<<endl;
   cout<<dp[3][0]<<endl;
 }
```

the second index of `dp` ranges from `0` to `5` (since you declared `int dp[5][6]` and C++ arrays are zero-based). However, you then loop the second index (`i` in your `for` loop) from `1` to `9`. Indices `6, 7, 8, 9` are therefore out of range and normally this would crash your program.

It doesn't crash because you've declared a 2d array, which gets allocated in a single contiguous block of memory, so `dp[1][6]` overflows into the next part of your 2d array. i.e. `dp[1][6]` is equivalent to `dp[2][0]`.

This is why, in the first case, you find `dp[2][0]` equals `1`.

However, when you change the declaration to `dp[100][100]`, then `6, 7, ...` are valid second indices, so it never overflows and `dp[2][0]` remains at its initialised value of `0`.

Comment: Thank You for the feedback. I was writing a dp solution for a question when I got this error. I had the notion that accessing an element out of bounds crashes the program.

Comment: @pratyushchaudhary technically, accessing a normal array with out-of-bounds indices causes *undefined behaviour*. That is, the standard says nothing about what the compiler/runtime should do. _Typically_ you'll find it just crashes, but *don't rely on it*. If you want "friendlier" error handling, use STL containers like `std::array<T>` or `std::vector<T>`. These are _much_ safer and the slight performance penalty is almost always worth it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to mention is dp[5][6] is a 2D array where there is 5 rows and each row having 6 columns. You can visualize it as a grid. But the reality is each rows are arranged sequentially one after another. First row can hold 0 to 5. Now when in the loop you are assigning dp[1][6]=1 it means dp[2][0] is assigned 1 as dp[1][5] is the last element of the 1st row and 6th element of first row is the 1st element of 2nd row. You will get same ans for dp[2][1], dp[2][2] and dp[2][3]. But will get a 0 at dp[2][4].

One thing to mention that it might be different in a different architecture. Again different compilers can work differently.